# How can PCs keep up when maneuver DCs increase so quickly?

Tags: combat, vehicles, difficulty-class, starfinder

Lots of maneuvers call for a DC of [some number]+2×[the ship's tier]. Yet as your character levels up (and your ship's tier with it), your max ranks in a given skill only increase by 1/level.

Thus, as you gain experience and get to know your ship better and modify it to suit you, it actually becomes *harder* to get it to do anything not in the base specs.

Coming off of 5e's bounded accuracy, this is a bit of a shock. Am I reading this right? Am I missing something? I know there are ASIs, but those don't happen that often — is there an assumption of assistive gear that would make maneuvers easier over time, or at least not harder?

Comment: Han Solo also is interested in a good answer to this problem... His ship's DC are crazy high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is an error.

The [errata](https://paizo.com/starfinder/faq) revises these DC's to be [number]+1.5×[the ship's tier]. This gives us results like this:

- Tier/Level 10 (DC 25)

  - 13 (skill) + 5 (ability) + 4 (ship) = +22 (85% chance)
- Tier/level 20 (DC 40)

  - 23 + 6 + 8 + 6 = +45 (95% chance)

So at least it wasn't my imagination - the devs also figured out this was silly, and made it so as long as you keep up with your skills, your ability to do maneuvers goes up over time, not down.

Answer (score 11):

Vehicle upgrades increase in quality as well as 'size' (for lack of a more encompassing term). For instance, your starship can get a Short-Range Scanner (range 5) that is Budget, Basic, or Advanced. Basic adds +2 and Advanced adds +4 to all related checks. Each range has a similar suite of options. Computers are a little more straightforward; they start at Basic (no bonus) then can be upgraded to Mk 1 (+1) and go up to Mk 8 (+8). Thrusters only provide 0, +1 or +2 bonus. You could of course get some of this early, but the higher your Tier, the more BP you have to use so you're more likely to meet the demand.

Does this offset the difficulty increase? Let's look at a difficult Computers check, assuming linear Mk increase over levels. I'm also assuming full skill ranks and that ability scores are allocated appropriately but not min/maxed.

- Tier/Level 1 DC 10+1.5*Tier = DC 11

  - 4 (skill+ class skill) + 3 (ability) + 0 (ship) = Estimated +7 (85% chance of success)
- Tier/level 5 (DC 17)

  - 8 (skill) + 4 (ability) + 2 (ship) = Estimated +14 (85% chance)
- Tier/Level 10 (DC 25)

  - 13 (skill) + 5 (ability) + 4 (ship) = +22 (85% chance)
- Tier/level 15 (DC 32)

  - 18 (skill) + 5 (ability) + 6 (ship) = +29 (85% chance)
- Tier/level 20 (DC 40)

  - 23 (skill) + 6 (ability) + 8 (ship) = +37 (85% chance)

Factoring in the [Errata](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1hi#v5748eaic9w55) linked by OP, the ability to succeed against average DC's are pretty static across the levels, assuming averages.

Piloting's numbers would be similar, but shifted to be a bit more difficult, but Pilots also get bonuses from Ship size and maneuverability that would be hard to summarize into bullets. There is also the Ace Pilot theme to help do their job.

### Ways to Increase your Vehicle Capability

- Skill Focus Feat (+3 Insight to chosen skill)<sup>1</sup>
- Skill Synergy Feat (Change to Class Skill or +2 Insight to 2 skills)<sup>1</sup>
- Personal Upgrade (+1 to +3 from increased ability scores)
- Other Equipment (IE Data Jack, Tool Kit/Specialized) (+2 to +6 Competence for Engineering or Computers)
- Higher Quality Parts (Varies)
- Smaller Ship (Pilot only)
- Better Maneuverability (Pilot only)
- Captain Encouragement (+2 one job per round, as Aid Another)
- Lashunta Race (+2 Racial to any 2 skills)
- Ysoki Race (+2 Racial to Engineering only)
- Envoy Class (+1d6 to 1d8+4 Insight; Diplomacy, Computers, and/or Engineering only; average +3.5-8.5)<sup>1</sup>
- Engineer Class* (7th level, ability to repair Starship Hull)
- Mystic Class Connection: Star Shaman (Piloting +1 to +7 Insight)<sup>1</sup>
- Operative Class (+1 to +6 Insight, all skills)<sup>1</sup>
- Operative Class Exploit: Uncanny Pilot (Reduce penalty when you're piloting and attacking simultaneously, situational +2 Circumstance to Piloting)<sup>2</sup>
- Technomancer Class (+1 to +6 Insight, Computers only)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>Insight bonuses do not stack, only the largest of these applies.
<sup>2</sup>Circumstance bonuses generally stack unless a GM indicates they don't.

---

For semantics, a Operative acting as your Science Officer, as above (Ranks [inc. Class Skill bonus] + Ability Mod + Equipment Bonus + Operative Bonus):

- Tier/Level 1 DC 10+2*Tier = DC 11

  - 4 + 3 + 0 + 1 = Estimated +8 (90% chance)
- Tier/level 5 (DC 17)

  - 8 + 4 + 2 + 2 = Estimated +16 (100% chance)
- Tier/Level 10 (DC 25)

  - 13 + 5 + 4 + 3 = +27 (105% chance)
- Tier/level 15 (DC 32)

  - 18 + 5 + 6 + 5 = +36 (115% chance)
- Tier/level 20 (DC 40)

  - 23 + 6 + 8 + 6 = +45 (110% chance)

Lashunta's have the ability to add another 10% to each of these.

While it is now possible for any class to succeed at their role, **it is still advisable to pick an appropriate Class, such as Operative or to have another way to gain significant Insight bonus.**

Comment: Thanks - your updated answer significantly reduces the WTF factor; specialists and/or Operatives can just about keep up. For the benefit of those of us who aren't used to typed bonuses, though, you might add that *none* of Skill Focus, Skill Synergy, Envoy Expertise, and Operative's Edge stack with each other.

Comment: Looks like there's been some [errata](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1hi#v5748eaic9w55) - interested in checking out the implications?

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look. It probably wont affect my answer too much, since I mostly looked at it from an optimizing PC's PoV, but I'll definitely update the DC's where appropriate.

Comment: @Ifusaso: Did you get a chance to update the answer if needed? The most recent edit seems to be months before your last comment.

Comment: It would seem I completely forgot to do so. Thank you, I'll update my DC's and %'s